# How convert date with strtotime and sort in foreach

Tags: php, sorting, date, strtotime

i have this code.

```
function getSubMenu($page){
```

```
$children=getChildren($page);   
$sliced = array_slice($children , 0, 10);

foreach ($sliced as $subpage){
    $title=returnPageField($subpage,'title');
    $date=returnPageField($subpage,'pubDate');
    $url=returnPageField($subpage,'slug');
    echo '<li><a href="/'.$url.'.html">'.$title.'</a>'.$date.'</li>';
}
```

}
 It echo subpage, but i need to sort (by date) this before echo. In 'pubDate' save date in format “l, F jS, Y - g:i A” (Fri, 18 Jul 2014 17:46:15 +0400) and sort not work. How convert with strtotime all date then sort and after echo? Thanks.

Comment: You should always save your dates in the database in a sortable date format. You also may have to take into account timezones (I usually solve that by saving into a standard timezone like UTC).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getSubMenu($page){
  $children=getChildren($page);

  // sorting by date
  usort($children, 'date_compare');

  $sliced = array_slice($children , 0, 10);

  foreach ($sliced as $subpage){
    $title=returnPageField($subpage,'title');
    $date=returnPageField($subpage,'pubDate');
    $url=returnPageField($subpage,'slug');
    echo '<li><a href="/'.$url.'.html">'.$title.'</a>'.$date.'</li>';
  }
} 

function date_compare($a, $b)
{
    $t1 = strtotime($a['pubDate']);
    $t2 = strtotime($b['pubDate']);
    return $t1 - $t2;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, when i replace **$a['pubDate']** on **returnPageField($a,'pubDate')** it work.